# Perl | Telegram Bot and sendPhoto method

Tags: perl, bots, telegram

I need help with **pure perl** (without WWW::Telegram::BotAPI) implementation of sendPhoto BotAPI method

Simple text i send without problem

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use JSON::MaybeXS;
....
....
   my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

   utf8::decode($message);
   my $p = {
            chat_id=>$groupid,
            parse_mode=>'HTML',
            text=>$message
    };

   my $response = $ua->request(
        POST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage',
        Content_Type    => 'application/json',
        Content         => JSON::MaybeXS::encode_json($p)
        );
...
```

But with sendPhoto (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) i have problem. Which JSON i must send to server if i want upload new image?

```
chat_id=>$groupid,
caption=>$message
photo=> { ? binary blob here ? }
```

Comment: Hmm. The docs say that the InputFile object should be posted using multipart/formdata. But that's strange.

Comment: Not using WWW::Telegram::BotAPI doesn't include borrowing from [its source](https://v1.metacpan.org/source/ROBERTOF/WWW-Telegram-BotAPI-0.07/lib/WWW/Telegram/BotAPI.pm#L80). I suggest you study how it's done there. Looks like you need to switch the content type. The author was nice enough to even put a link to how to do it with HTTP::Request::Common in the source. And in general, the source has entertaining comments and is worth a read.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use the module?

Comment: @Borodin just for increased knowledge. My bot is too simple, send message and stop. For service notification only, not for dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i make an mistake)

for file upload, I do not need a json!

wrong!

```
my $p = [ chat_id => $groupid,
          caption => 'image caption',
          photo => ["/tmp/pdf.png"]
];

my $response = $ua->request(
POST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendPhoto',
Content_Type    => 'form-data',
Content         => JSON::MaybeXS::encode_json($msg)
);
```

valid below

```
my $p = [ chat_id => $groupid,
          caption => 'image caption',
          photo => ["/tmp/pdf.png"]
];

my $response = $ua->request(
POST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendPhoto',
Content_Type    => 'form-data',
Content         => $msg
);
```